# Updating SharePoint(2010) List from Access 2010 - Error Executing Bulk Query

Tags: microsoft-access, bulk

I've been having an issue running this query in an Access 2010 application. The issue arises when the end-user clicks a button that executes this query.

> UPDATE [Renewal Stop Request] SET [Renewal Stop Request].[Log ID] = [forms]![frmRequestReview]![bxLogID], [Renewal Stop Request].Status = 'Archived' WHERE ((([Renewal Stop Request].Title)=[forms]![frmRequestReview]![bxTitle]));

This query ran without issue for a couple weeks but now the end users receive the below error message fairly frequently.

> "There were errors executing the bulk query or sending the data to the server. Reconnect the tables to resolve the conflicts or discard the pending changes".

After this error appears, SharePoint connections are disconnected and the end user has to exit the tool. The end users are eventually able to execute the query after an unknown number of tries. So in the short term the error is not a "show-stopper" but it is a drain on the end users' time.

I see [Errors executing bulk query when updating a Sharepoint Linked List from Access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87028/errors-executing-bulk-query-when-updating-a-sharepoint-linked-list-from-access) has had similar issues but the answers there don't seem to apply to my problem. The UPDATE query is simple and the SharePoint list(RENEWAL STOP REQUEST) is ~750 rows.

Since this query(button) works occasionally for some users and all the time from other people's computers, it doesn't appear to be a connectivity issue. Could this be related to Users' settings? Do I have to refresh the SharePoint connection if the query runs? I've tried to figure out a solution but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing multiple users were using this tool and reading [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-2010-list-with-Access-2010-975BFB97-C799-4FCE-B7CC-3DB3B397F116), I figured it had the error had to do with the user contribution permission. For one person it was working and for everyone else it was not. It turns out that only that 1 person had the ability to create/edit/delete on the SharePoint Site and it's lists.

We've changed over one person's contribution permission and early results are indicating that it worked.